# Bash arithmetic issues

Tags: bash

I have the following script, pretty self explanatory but I'm getting super strange issues.

Multiply gives me 0

Division multiplies

Any insight would be awesome!

Thanks,
Austen

```
n1=$1
op=$2
n2=$3


case "$op" in

+)
        echo $(( $n1 + $n2 ))
        ;;
-)
        echo $(( $n1 - $n2 ))
        ;;

*)      echo $(( $n1 * $n2 ))
        ;;

/)      echo $(( $n1 / $n2 ))
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: You need `'*')` (with quotes) otherwise the wildcard matches _anything_.

Comment: It may interest some readers to know that bash will happily interpret the operator into the arithmetic expression. To wit: `x=+; echo $(( 1 $x 2 )); # outputs 3`

Comment: @kojiro: Handy to know. Note that it only works if you `$`-prefix the variable reference (whereas the prefix is usually optional in arithmetic contexts).

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah, I found that interesting as well, particularly because the AE does expand the unprefixed parameter, but then tries to dereference it further when it discovers it's not an integer. Why it doesn't do that with the `$x` form I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, but this is how I had to fix it:

```
#!/bin/bash

n1=$1
op=$2
n2=$3

if [ "$op" == 'x' ]
then
echo $(( $n1 * $n2 ))
else
echo $(( $n1 $op $n2 ))
fi
```

Comment: This fix just works around the problem without requiring you to understand what was wrong with your code before. Furthermore, it uses the `==` bashism and could still fail for several reasons, including that you don't seem to validate `$op` at all. I would advise you to ask for clarification from @gniourf_gniourf or me about the original problem.

Answer (score 3):

@gniourf_gniourf's comment is 90% of the answer and fully explains why "division multiplies". The other 10% is that you need to quote the `*` argument when you pass it to this code, or else it will glob expand and your third argument will be some filename, which, inside the arithmetic expression, will probably evaluate to `0`. That explains why "Multiply gives me 0".

You could also solve this by setting the `noglob` shell option to prevent globs from expanding.

Compare:

```
echo *
set -f
echo *
```

Comment: +1 for the analysis and explanation; using `set -f` just to be able to pass an unquoted `*` to a script is probably overkill, though.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `bc` as bash does not handle floats:

```
echo $((4/3))
1
```

Using `bc`:

```
echo "4/3" | bc -l
1.33333333333333333333
```

Comment: That's handy to know, but it's not even clear whether non-integer division is a requirement; the OP's problem is unrelated to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

[@kojiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24367886/45375) explains the problem with the original code well (`*` must be *quoted* to prevent its interpretation as the default `case` branch inside the script, and to prevent pathname expansion when passed as an argument).

@kojiro also points out that you can use variable references in place of literal arithmetic operators in arithmetic expansion expressions (`$((...))`). *Caveat*: only works as `$op` - with `$` prefix! - not just `op` (the `$` prefix is otherwise optional in arithmetic contexts in bash).

With that in mind, here's a simplified solution that also performs operator checking. (To make it fully robust, the *operands* would have to be checked, too).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

n1=$1 op=$2 n2=$3

 # Allow 'x' to be passed as an alias for '*' (multiplication).
[[ "$op" == 'x' ]] && op='*'

 # Ensure that the operator is valid.
case $op in
    +|-|'*'|/) # note the quoted '*', needed to prevent interpretation as wildcard
        ;;
    *) # proper use of unquoted *: the everything-else branch
        echo "Error: Unexpected operator: $op" >&2
        exit 1 
esac

 # Perform the calculation. Note how the operator is provided via variable $op.
 # Note how the reference to variable `op` _must_ be `$`-prefixed in this case,
 # unlike the other two references.
echo $(( n1 $op n2 ))
```